# Define a global Method in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web

When using Vue filters, one can create a global filter like this

```
Vue.filter('capitalize', function (value) {
  if (!value) return ''
  value = value.toString()
  return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)
})

new Vue({
  // ...
})
```

I what to create a global method that I can reuse in any component, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by defining a global [Mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) with the "global" method(s):

```
Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    myMethod: function () {
      // ...
    }
  }
});
```